regression: mergeDebugResources xliff 1.2 bad url problem
I have an android studio reporting:
:app:mergeDebugResources: error.
Can not extract resource from com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@17e23bc1
Opening >>project-base<</app/build/intermediates/incremental/debug/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/value.xml(given in log entry) shows an obsolete xmlns value of 'http://schemas.android.com/tools' and the 'urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2'.
Schemas.android.com does not exist.
10 years old: Why is Android Studio reporting "URI is not registered"?.
14 years old :How do you resolve a URN?.
The answers given in using 'build rebuildProject' and lookups at http://www.lexml.gov.br don't work anymore. I have restarted the android studio multiple times. Similar projects don't report any such problem.The '
I can't find an xsd file for any version of the xliff standard.
Why is this obsolete xmlns being used?
I could use xmlcatalog and rewriteURI but I can not find the xsd....
Thx in advance

You need xmlcatalog installed.
This file:
<?xml version="1.0"?>   
 <!DOCTYPE catalog PUBLIC "-//OASIS//DTD Entity Resolution XML Catalog
V1.0//EN"   
"http://www.oasis-open.org/committees/entity/release/1.0/catalog.dtd"
 > <catalog xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:entity:xmlns:xml:catalog">       <rewriteURI uriStartString="http://schemas.android.com/tools"  
 rewritePrefix="https://docs.oasis-open.org/xliff/xliff-core/v2.1v2.1/os/schemas/xliff_core_2.0.xsd"
 >

